# Numpy data types: data type not understood

Tags: python, numpy, types

still fairly new to Numpy in Python...I'm trying to build up my own array from RINEX data (see example):

```
G13 2014 01 02 02 00 00  .440594740212D-04 -.375166564481D-11  .000000000000D+00
      .290000000000D+02  .705937500000D+02  .382980238378D-08 -.135945866650D+01
      .353716313839D-05  .509947887622D-02  .137723982334D-04  .515366394615D+04
      .352800000000D+06 -.819563865662D-07  .312956454846D+01 -.633299350739D-07
      .979542877504D+00  .129500000000D+03  .219020237787D+01 -.757495838456D-08
     -.431803700643D-09  .100000000000D+01  .177300000000D+04  .000000000000D+00
      .240000000000D+01  .000000000000D+00 -.111758708954D-07  .290000000000D+02
      .345618000000D+06  .400000000000D+01
```

I'm using the following code for initialised matrix:

```
parameter_block_list = np.empty(cs.TOTAL_SATS, cs.RINEX_NAVIGATION_PARAMETERS) * np.NaN
```

The problem is the conversion of the numbers in the RINEX file block, where each number uses "D" as an exponential. Is there a way in Numpy to make a data type conversion that caters for such data formats? The error I'm receiving is:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: If you replace the `D` with an `e`, would it work?

Comment: I think you have two different problems - the error you're seeing is a result of the arguments you've given to `np.empty`, not the format of your data.

Comment: I think `np.empty` takes a tuple of dimensions doesn't it? `np.empty((cs.TOTAL_SATS, cs.RINEX_NAVIGATION_PARAMETERS))`

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're getting `data type not understood` is that in passing the dimensions of your array to `empty` as separate arguments, the first is being treated as the `shape` and the second as the `dtype` -- see [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html). Perhaps you mean to pass the `shape` as a tuple:

```
parameter_block_list = np.empty((cs.TOTAL_SATS, cs.RINEX_NAVIGATION_PARAMETERS)) * np.NaN
```